# Анимация на Javascript c полями input

Tags: javascript, анимация

Есть блок `div` и два `input`

1. Отвечает за свойства `left` или `marginLeft` блока `div`.
2. Отвечает за свойства `top` или `marginTop`.

Так вот задача при нажатии на блок он передвигался до значения `input`-ов с анимацией

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    .ground {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background: orange;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .ball {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: darkblue;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>
    <div class="ground">
        <div class="ball" id="ball">
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="text" class="x">

    <script>
        let ball = document.querySelector('.ball');

        ball.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
           let timer = setInterval(function () {
                evt.preventDefault();
                let inputX = document.querySelector('.x');
                let step = 0;
                step += 2;
                ball.style.left = step + 'px';
                if (step > inputX.value) clearInterval(timer);
            },20)
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.ball` у тебя квадратный, поэтому он не катится и стоит на месте. Если серьезно - используй `getBoundingRect` для получения исходных координат, и опиши `transition` в CSS. Использовать таймер для этого не надо.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, только я не понимаю как рилизовать код, поможешь пожалуйста

Comment: Ок. Координаты для перемещения `.ball` должны быть относительными (его текущей позиции), или абсолютными?

Comment: Координаты должны быть абсолютными

Comment: @yar85, это учебная задачка, тут всё должно быть просто. просто подстановка в `el.style.left`. анимашка одноразовая, потом сброс.

Comment: @АлексейЕрёменко https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/G4QwTgBAJglsBcEASAVAsgGQKIBsCmAtngHYAuA3ALABQswAdAM6kCe+9+AZqTXU6+1IB7AA5A используй IDE и всё будет проще

Comment: @qwabra, Все-таки уточнить, это никогда не лишнее (вдруг оказалась бы учебная задача на относительные и абсолютные координаты в документе).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const inpX = document.querySelector('.x'), 
      inpY = document.querySelector('.y'), 
      ball = document.querySelector('.ball'); 
ball.addEventListener('click', function () {
  this.style.left = (+inpX.value || 0) + 'px'; 
  this.style.top  = (+inpY.value || 0) + 'px'; 
});
```

```css
.ground {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px; height: 500px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: orange; }

.ball {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  transition: none 1s ease-out; 
  transition-property: top, left;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  background: center / 100% no-repeat radial-gradient(circle at 33% 33%, #ddf 1%, #46f 3%, darkblue, #224 67%, #544 85%);
  cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<input class="x" type="number" value="200"> :
<input class="y" type="number" value="40">

<div class="ground">
  <div class="ball" id="ball"></div>
</div>
```

---

А если все же хочется сделать неразумно (через `setInterval`), то:

```js
const inpX = document.querySelector('.x'), 
      inpY = document.querySelector('.y'), 
      ball = document.querySelector('.ball'), 
      cStl = getComputedStyle(ball); 
const duration = 1000,
      delay = 20, 
      steps = duration / delay;
let interval, iteration; 

ball.addEventListener('click', function () {
  clearInterval(interval); 
  iteration = 0;
  let x = parseInt(cStl.left), 
      y = parseInt(cStl.top), 
      stepX = ((+inpX.value || 0) - x) / steps, 
      stepY = ((+inpY.value || 0) - y) / steps; 
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.style.left = (x += stepX) + 'px'; 
    this.style.top  = (y += stepY) + 'px'; 
    if (++iteration >= steps)
      clearInterval(interval); 
  }, delay); 
});
```

```css
.ground {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px; height: 500px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: orange; }

.ball {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  background: center / 100% no-repeat radial-gradient(circle at 33% 33%, #ddf 1%, #46f 3%, darkblue, #224 67%, #544 85%);
  cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<input class="x" type="number" value="200"> :
<input class="y" type="number" value="40">

<div class="ground">
  <div class="ball" id="ball"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: сделать неразумно© иногда анимация на JS работает идеально, а на CSS дико лагает ...